# How create/use services with OpenRC?

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm used to create and use services with systemd like that :

XXXX.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Report Service

[Service]
Type=Simple
ExecStart=/path/to/my/script.sh
```

XXXX.timer :

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for Report Service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 2:00:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

But now, I've to use OpenRC and I don't really understand how it works !

There is someone to explain how OpenRC work and based on my example, how to create a service with OpenRC, in order to learn how to use it ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best option to learn is [this](https://github.com/OpenRC/openrc/blob/master/service-script-guide.md).

The base script is like this:

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run
# Copyright 2021 Gentoo Authors
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2

name="service"
description=""
command="/path/to/dir/"
command_args="${service_args}"
#command_user="user:user"

depend() {

}
```